# Do these conditions imply countable additivity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $S$ be a semi-ring of subsets of $X$. Let $\mu :S\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a set function with the following properties:

1. $\mu(X) = 1, \mu(\emptyset)=0$
2. For any decreasing sequence $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ with $\bigcap_n A_n= \emptyset$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n)= 0$
3. If $A_1,...,A_n (\in S)$ are mutually disjoint and $\sqcup_{i=1}^n A_i \in S$, then $\mu(\sqcup_{i=1}^n A_i )=\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_n)$

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a mutually disjoint sequence in $S$ with $\sqcup_n A_n\in S$. Then, can we show that $\mu(\sqcup_n A_n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(A_n)$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. First, show that if $B_n\subset B_{n+1}$ and $\cup_n B_n = B\in S$, then $\mu(B_n)\to\mu(B)$.

Comment: @amsmath Could you give me some more details? Please note that it is a semi-ring, not a ring.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I guess you assume $X\in S$?

Comment: @amsmath Yes! {}{}{}

Answer (score 0):

If $(B_{n})$ is increasing, and if we let $B=\bigcup_{n}B_{n}$, then $(B_{n}^{c}\cap B)$ is decreasing and $\bigcap_{n}B_{n}^{c}\cap B=\emptyset$.

**If $B_{n}^{c}\cap B\in S$.**

Then $\lim_{n}\mu(B_{n}^{c}\cap B)=0$ and hence $\lim_{n}\mu(B_{n}\cup B^{c})=1$ and $\lim_{n}\mu(B_{n})+\mu(B^{c})=1$ by the disjointness and hence $\lim_{n}\mu(B_{n})=\mu(B)$.

Now let $A=\bigcup_{n}A_{n}$, one has $B_{n}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}$ is increasing, so $\lim_{n}\mu(B_{n})=\mu(A)$ and $\mu(B_{n})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(A_{k})$, then $\mu(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{n})$.

Comment: Oops. It's a **semi-ring**. $B_n^c \cap B$ need not be an element of $S$

Comment: Then maybe it's not true.

Comment: What more conditions should I need.. I know that finitely additivity + countably monotone $\Rightarrow$ premeasure

Comment: I get into this situation when I was proving something.. I want to know if there is some requirements to prove that it's a premeasure, so that I can try to derive that requirements from my given problem.

Comment: As you said, the $S$ better to contain those intersection, if not, I have no idea neither, sorry.

Comment: I was trying to extend the property 2 to the ring extension $\bar{\mu}$ of $\mu$ with the domain $R(S)$ (The ring generated by $S$).. but I am stuck

Comment: I will notify you if I manage to fix that.

Comment: Mate, $B_{n}^{c}\in S$ so $B_{n}^{c}\cap B\in S$.

Comment: @user284331 If $B\in S$ and $A_k^c\in S$ for all $k$, then yes. But what if $B_n\notin S$? Then $\mu(B_n)$ is not defined.

Comment: @user284331 $B_n^c$ is a finite disjoint union of elements of $S$, but not an element of $S$.

Comment: I think I am confused for a while, okay, then I have no idea.

Comment: @user284331 :D Like your honesty. I don't have a clue either.

Comment: Defineability is not really a matter, because we can extend the domain of $\mu$ to "the ring generated by $S$". Let $\bar{\mu}$ be this extension. It can be shown that $\bar{\mu}$ is also an additive function. Problem is that the property $2$, only holds for elements in $S$.. If we can extend the property $2$ to this extension $\bar{\mu}$, we are done. However, I cannot show this..